# Pig throws error for simple Group by and count occurrence task

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Using Hadoop's PIG-Latin to find the number of occurrences of unique search strings from a search engine log file.([click here to view  the sample log file](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s308/sh/09e9e3d2-074f-42e3-8b23-0ded7550c530/caa7d12a88c47c6d66d3fa08d9b2d18c))
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Pig script

```
excitelog = load '/user/hadoop/input/excite-small.log' using PigStorage() AS
(encryptcode:chararray, numericid:int, searchstring:chararray);                                        

GroupBySearchString = GROUP excitelog by searchstring;    

searchStrFrq = foreach GroupBySearchString Generate group as searchstring,count(searchstring);
```

Error encountered

```
 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve count using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do:

```
searchStrFrq = foreach GroupBySearchString Generate group as searchstring,
                                                COUNT(excitelog) as kount;
```

This is because the way grouping works in pig, `GroupBySearchString` would be a bag of `{group, excitelog}`, where `excitelog` is itself a bag of all tuples matching the group. `COUNT` is a UDF takes a bag as input and returns the number of tuples in the bag. So, `COUNT(excitelog)` will then give you the number of tuples matching the `group`.

Comment: Its still throwing the same error after making the changes as instructed by you.

Comment: Also make sure `group as` is lower case, otherwise you will run into error: `ERROR 1025: Projected field [GROUP] does not exist in schema`.

Answer (score 0):

Function names PigStorage and COUNT are case sensitive.
so one need to keep COUNT function like as below:

```
wordcount = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group , COUNT(words);
```